# Restricted Read Over Contribute Permission Sp 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-server, splist

I have a Document library where **userA** has been placed under 2 groups. **Group1** has been given Restricted Read and **Group2** has been given Contribute. In this Scenario **UserA** cant edit the document even after he has Contribute(default) permission. It is only providing his read access to the resources of that document library.

So my question is when we have restricted read and contribute assigned to a document library of which the user is part of both group. How does the permission work.

Sp version : 2013 standard version

Sp template: Team Site

Comment: what error user is getting? are both groups are site collection level?

Comment: I am not getting any error but Restricted read is overriding the contribute permissions upon my user.

Answer (score 0):

UserA should have contribute, SharePoint gives the highest (or highest pieces from each)

Use the check user permissions button on that username to ensure he is actually receiving contribute, also make sure you don't have unique permissions set on the document he is trying to work on.

Comment: Yes i used check user permission and found user was assigned restricted read and contribute both. but until i took him out of restricted read group, he cant add or edit an item in that library.

Comment: Very strange, it probably has to do with the fact that restricted read comes from the publishing tools. I'm not finding any information about this though in the official docs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on publishing tools. i am confused too i always had an assumption that higher permission would override the lower permission level.

Comment: Restricted read is not a "normal" permission level, it is only available in site collections with the SharePoint Publishing feature activated. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640(v=office.15).aspx